# How do I get the address of an object with an interface?

Tags: d

This is related to [Disposing a class with an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868594/disposing-a-class-with-an-interface)

```d
interface Bar{
}
class Foo: Bar{
    int i;
    this(int _i){
        i = _i;
    }
}

void main(){
    import std.experimental.allocator.mallocator;
    import std.experimental.allocator;
    auto f = Mallocator.instance.make!Foo(42);
    Bar b = f;
    void* p = (cast(void*)b);
    void* p1 = (cast(void*)f);
    writeln(p);
    writeln(p1);
    Mallocator.instance.dispose(b);// Bad
}
```

Prints:

```
1EBE438 
1EBE420
```

So the address of `Bar` has an offset of 24 bytes. That can't be right. How do I get the correct address from an interface?

Comment: What makes you think that this is incorrect?

Comment: @Codor Well `f` and `b` are pointing to the same thing, so the address should be the same or am I wrong?

Comment: No, intuitively your reasoning makes totally sense; however I would be surprised if this is really formally specified. I would guess that `p` and `p1` actually are _not_ the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://dlang.org/spec/abi.html#classes:

> Casting a class object to an interface consists of adding the offset of the interface's corresponding vptr to the address of the base of the object. Casting an interface ptr back to the class type it came from involves getting the correct offset to subtract from it from the object.Interface entry at vtbl[0].

I don't know why this is necessary, but it seems to explain the different addresses.

Comment: Casting to Object then casting back to void* I think will get the original class address. Check for null though!